# Bspwm is not working

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, script, window-manager

I have installed [Bspwm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft:Bspwm) from [AUR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux#Arch_User_Repository_(AUR)) on my [EndeavourOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EndeavourOS) distribution which was initially running the GNOME desktop environment.

I followed all the instructions on the Arch Linux wiki for Bspwm. I have made `sxhkdrc` and `bspwmrc` files as executable. I am posting my bspwmrc, .xinitrc and sxhkdrc.

When I open Bspwm from the gdm login screen by clicking that little cog at the bottom right, but I just get a blank screen. None of the keybindings are working. I even tried starting Bspwm from tty by using *startx*, but nothing works.

**bspwmrc:**

```
#! /bin/sh


BSPDIR="$HOME/.config/bspwm"

sxhkd -c .config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc &
pgrep -x sxhkd > /dev/null || sxhkd &

bspc monitor -d I II III IV V VI VII VIII IX X

bspc config border_width         2
bspc config window_gap          12

bspc config split_ratio          0.52
bspc config borderless_monocle   true
bspc config gapless_monocle      true

bspc rule -a Gimp desktop='^8' state=floating follow=on
bspc rule -a Chromium desktop='^2'
bspc rule -a mplayer2 state=floating
bspc rule -a Kupfer.py focus=on
bspc rule -a Screenkey manage=off

##----------Autostart------------##

killall -9 xsettingsd sxhkd dunst ksuperkey xfce4-power-manager

#xsettingsd --config="$BSPDIR"/xsettingsd &

if [[ ! `pidof xfce-polkit` ]]; then
    /usr/lib/xfce-polkit/xfce-polkit &
fi


sxhkd -c .config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc &

ksuperkey -e 'Super_L=Alt_L|F1' &
ksuperkey -e 'Super_R=Alt_L|F1' &


xfce4-power-manager &


xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr

exec mpd &

exec copyq
```

**shkdrc:**

```
##---------- Keybindings for  bspwm -----------##



###---------- Keybindings for bspwm ----------##

# Terminal (alacritty)
super + Return
    alacritty --config-file .config/alacritty/alacritty.yml

# Terminal (floating)
super + shift + Return
    alacritty --float

# Terminal (fullscreen)
super + t
    alacritty --full

##---------- Rofi Launcher & Menus ----------##

# Rofi App Launcher
alt + F1
    sh ~/.config/bspwm/rofi/bin/launcher

# Rofi Network Menu
super + n
    nmd

# Rofi Themes Menu
ctrl + alt + t
    sh ~/.config/bspwm/rofi/bin/themes

# Rofi Menus/Applets
super + {w,m,x,r,s}
    sh ~/.config/bspwm/rofi/bin/{windows,mpd,powermenu,asroot,screenshot}

##---------- Applications ----------##

# Launch Apps
super + shift + {f,w,e}
    {thunar,firefox,geany}

# Launch Firefox priate window
alt + shift + w
    {firefox -private-window}

# Terminal Apps
ctrl + alt + {v,r,h}
    alacritty --config-file ~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml -e {vim,ranger,htop}

# Color Picker
super + p
    color-gpick

# Lockscreen
ctrl + alt + l
    betterlockscreen --lock

##---------- System Keys ----------##

# Take a screenshot
Print
    takeshot --now

# Take screenshot in 5 second
alt + Print
    takeshot --in5

# Take screenshot in 10 second
shift + Print
    takeshot --in10

# Take screenshot of active window
ctrl + Print
    takeshot --win

# Take screenshot of area
ctrl + alt + Print
    takeshot --area

# Brighness control
XF86MonBrightness{Up,Down}
    brightness{ --inc, --dec}

# Volume control
XF86Audio{RaiseVolume,LowerVolume}
    volume{ --inc, --dec}

XF86AudioMute
    volume --toggle

XF86AudioMicMute
    volume --toggle-mic

# Music control
XF86Audio{Next,Prev,Play,Stop}
    mpc {next,prev,toggle,stop}


##---------- Bspwm ----------##

# Close App
super + {_,shift + }c
    bspc node -{c,k}

# Reload Keybindings
super + Escape
    pkill -USR1 -x sxhkd

# kill window
ctrl + alt + Escape
    xkill

# Quit/Restart bspwm
ctrl + shift + {q,r}
    bspc {quit,wm -r}

# Split horizontal, vertical or cancel
super + {h,v,q}
    bspc node -p {east,south,cancel}

# Preselect the ratio
super + ctrl + {1-9}
    bspc node -o 0.{1-9}

# Fullscreen or Monocle
super + f
#    bspc desktop -l next
    bspc node -t "~"fullscreen

# Toggle beetwen floating & tiled
super + space
    bspc node -t "~"{floating,tiled}

# Pseudo Tiled & tiled mode
super + shift + space
#super + {p,t}
    bspc node -t "~"{pseudo_tiled,tiled}

# Set the node flags
super + ctrl + {m,x,y,z}
    bspc node -g {marked,locked,sticky,private}

# Send the window to another edge of the screen
super + {_,shift + }{Left,Down,Up,Right}
    bspc node -{f,s} {west,south,north,east}

# Change focus to next window, including floating window
alt + {_,shift + }Tab
    bspc node -f {next.local,prev.local}

# Switch workspace
ctrl + alt + {Left,Right}
    bspc desktop -f {prev.local,next.local}

# Switch to last opened workspace
super + {Tab,grave}
    bspc {node,desktop} -f last

# Send focused window to another workspace
super + {_,shift + }{1-8}
    bspc {desktop -f,node -d} '^{1-8}'

# Expanding windows
super + control + {Left,Right,Up,Down}
    bspc node -z {left -20 0,right 20 0,top 0 -20,bottom 0 20}

## Shrinking windows
super + alt + {Left,Right,Up,Down}
    bspc node -z {left 20 0,right -20 0,top 0 20,bottom 0 -20}

## Move floating windows
alt + shift + {Left,Down,Up,Right}
    bspc node -v {-20 0,0 20,0 -20,20 0}

# Hide/Unhide Window
super + shift + i
    winmask

##---------- EOF ----------##
```

**xinitc:**

```
#!/bin/bash

exec bspwm
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.